# How to authenticate Guest/Unauthenticated users with API Gateway Cognito Authorizer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

In API gateway you can setup a Cognito Authorizer that references a Cognito User Pool for authentication. For verification, API Gateway expects the Cognito User Pool JWT token to be set in the Authorization header.

Using 'aws-sdk' and 'amazon-cognito-identity-js' NPM packages, how can I create guest/unauthenticated users and retrieve the JWT token to pass to API Gateway? By Guest/unauthenticated, I mean not even having a username or email. Or, is this not possible with the current APIs?

Amplify (built on top of Cognito) appears to have something similar: https://docs.amplify.aws/sdk/auth/guest-access/q/platform/android

Thoughts?

Comment: One piece that's often missed in these types of questions is that you don't have to attach the authorizer to every route on the gateway. You are allowed to have public routes that are unauthenticated that integrate to the same lambda while the lambda inspects the path on the event to limit the scope of the behavior. It's generally safer to keep a separate stripped down lambda tho, but not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognito User Pool is an authentication provider. This is separate from unauthenticated access that is provided by Identity pool. You cannot use the default cognito authorizer in API Gateway for validating the token. However, you can use a custom lambda authorizer that will take token and confirm it is valid for your identity pool.

Comment: By the way, what does the Amplify SDK creates a 'true' guest/unauthenticated user that can be validated by an API Gateway Cognito authorizer?

Comment: Don't know about amplify but identity pool creates temporary aws credentials for "guests" without having to register. Amplify just fetches these credentials from ID pool.